# Select the lastest one of each result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Say if I have a table similar to this but including more columns and more rows (These are the only relevant ones):

```
+-------+----+
| name  | id |
+-------+----+
| james | 1  |
| james | 2  |
| james | 3  |
| adam  | 4  |
| max   | 5  |
| adam  | 6  |
| max   | 7  |
| adam  | 8  |
+-------+----+
```

How could I get it so that it would only show the `max(id)` from each `name` like:

```
+-------+----+
| name  | id |
+-------+----+
| adam  | 8  |
| max   | 7  |
| james | 3  |
+-------+----+
```

I currently just have this

```
"select * from table order by id desc"
```

but this just shows the latest ids. I only want to be able to see one of each name.

---

So basically show only the highest `id` of each `name`

Comment: @toxalot does that not take ages to do?!

Comment: It doesn't take much time really and makes the question much easier to read.

Comment: Based on your comments to Gordon Linoff's answer, you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Answer (score 3):

You would use aggregation and `max()`:

```
select name, max(id)
from table t
group by name
order by max(id) desc
limit 40;
```

EDIT:

If you need `select *` with the highest `id`, then use the `not exists` approach:

```
select *
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.id > t.id)
order by id desc
limit 40;
```

The "not exists" essentially says:  "Get me all rows in the table where there is no other row with the same name and a higher id".  That is a round-about way of getting the maximum row.

Comment: I have tried this`"select name, max(id), comunicate, session_number, date
from social
group by name
order by max(id) desc
limit 40;"` but this picks the earliest id

Comment: @Maximilian . . . If you have more columns, you should ask another question, with appropriate data and your desired results.  That question is different from the one you asked.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to leverage a non-standard `GROUP BY` extension in MySQL

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT *
    FROM table1
   ORDER BY id DESC
) q
 GROUP BY name
 -- LIMIT 40
```

or another way is to grab a max id per name first and then join back to your table to fetch all other columns

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(id) id
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY name
   -- LIMIT 40
) q JOIN table1 t
    ON q.id = t.id
 ORDER BY name;
```

Output:

```
|  NAME | ID |
|-------|----|
|  adam |  8 |
| james |  3 |
|   max |  7 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/586a34/3)** demo

Comment: OP wants results in descending order by `id` not `name`.

Comment: I would not recommend the first query even though MySQL supports it. The values returned for non-aggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY expression are indeterminate. Although selecting from an ordered subquery does appear to solve this, I would not want to rely on this behavior.